# BlackBerry - Set the text width of a EditField from a changeListener event

Tags: blackberry, java-me

If the length returned by `input.getText()` is greater than 13, the last character entered by the user should not appear on the edit field. If the 13th character is a ',' the program should allow 2 additional characters after the ','. That way, the maximum length of the edit field would be 16.

What would be an option to limit the text width of an EditField like this?

```
input = new BorderedEditField();

input.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {             
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if(input.getText().length() < 13)
            input.setText(pruebaTexto(input.getText()));
        else
            //do not add the new character to the EditField
    }
});

public static String pruebaTexto(String r){
    return r+"0";
}
```

Comment: Explain your question a little bit.

Comment: if the length returned by input.getText() is greater than 13, the last character entered by the user should not appear on the edit field. Is it clear?

Comment: Okay, if I understand correctly, then you need a EditField which can have at most 13 characters, is it? If yes then you can use `setMaxSize(int size)`. Also this can be done while constructing EditField instance using `public EditField(String label, String initialValue, int maxNumChars, long style)`. Check API Documentation for more information, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/EditField.html, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BasicEditField.html.

Comment: thanks Rupak. I added this to the else clause, but maybe it is not that elegant: input.setText(input.getText().substring(0, input.getText().length()-1));

Comment: I didn't understand this sentence, `I added this to the else clause`. I think you don't need to modify the text, because if you set the max number of characters allowed in a EditField, then it will never take extra characters as input. Why you are trying to modify text of `input`?

Comment: well, I didn't mentioned it, but if after the last character (13), the user enters ',', the program should allow to enter 2 characters more after the ','. That way, the maximum length of the edit field would be 16. I´ll try your solution later anyway. Thanks!

Comment: You missed most complex part of your question. Limiting max chars will not help you in this case. You can override the `keyChar` or similar methods to get control over every key press event, api link http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BasicEditField.html#keyChar%28char,%20int,%20int%29. Wish you luck :).

Comment: I have posted an answer based on my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have coded a simple `BorderedEditField` class which extends [`EditField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/EditField.html). The method, [`protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BasicEditField.html#keyChar%28char,%20int,%20int%29) of this class gets modified so that manipulation of `EditField`'s default behavior is possible. If you found this example helpful, then you can improve the implementation.

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Characters;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    public MyScreen() {
        BorderedEditField ef = new BorderedEditField();
        ef.setLabel("Label: ");

        add(ef);
    }
}

class BorderedEditField extends EditField {
    private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 13;
    private static final int MAX_LENGTH_EXCEPTION = 16;

    private static final char SPECIAL_CHAR = ',';

    protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
        // Need to add more rules here according to your need.
        if (key == Characters.DELETE || key == Characters.BACKSPACE) {
            return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
        }
        int curTextLength = getText().length();
        if (curTextLength < MAX_LENGTH) {
            return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
        }
        if (curTextLength == MAX_LENGTH) {
            char spChar = getText().charAt(MAX_LENGTH - 1);
            return (spChar == SPECIAL_CHAR) ? super.keyChar(key, status, time) : false;
        }
        if (curTextLength > MAX_LENGTH && curTextLength < MAX_LENGTH_EXCEPTION) {
            return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```